# 182-Day T-Bill vs. 91-Day T-Bill

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, actuarial-science

I am trying to understand how T-Bills work and it would be great if someone could explain me using the following question

> At $t=0$ Smith buys a 182-Day T-Bill with a simple annual discount rate of $10\%$. At $t=91$ Smith sells his T-Bill.  At that moment, the "prevailing quoted annual discount rate of a 91-Day T-Bill is also $10%$."  Find the actual rate of return (91-Day interest rate) that Smith earned during the time he held the T-Bill.

I am thinking that if $d=10\%$ then $i=11.111 \dots \%$ .

So at $t=91$ the interest earned is approximately

$$\frac{1}{4}(11.111 \dots \%)$$

So, I want to say that Smith earned that much, but the answer seems to be about $2.66\%$.

How do we get this?

Comment: If $d = 0.1$ then $i \neq .11111...$ because we're talking about simple interest, not compound interest. $i = d/(1-dt)$ for simple interest...

Comment: Okay let me try this.  Simple interest is $1+it$ and the discount can be calculated from $(1+it)^{-1}=1-dt$ ?

Comment: We can take the starting balance, add interest, to get the ending balance. Alternatively, we can take the ending balance, subtract the discount, to get the starting balance.

Comment: I now think the answer is $2.77%$  does anyone agree?

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea whether this is correct but $$\frac{\left(100-10\times\frac{91}{365}\right)-\left(100-10\times\frac{182}{365}\right)}{\left(100-10\times\frac{182}{365}\right)}\times 100\approx 2.623991$$ while if you [replaced $365$ by $360$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention#Actual.2F360) it would give about $2.662376$.

This looks like a stupid way to work out interest rates, but who said bankers were clever?

Comment: Bankers are extremely clever, and, not unlike 99.9% of homework problems, this question shows a stupidly oversimplified situation which would never occur in practice.